# Problem with tabularx

Tags: tables

The following code does not work ??

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\vrulehg}[1]
{\makebox[#1][c]{\rule{1pt}{0.5cm}}}% rule for vertical bar cell

\newcommand{\hrulehg}[3]{% hgrule{5cm}{c}{2}
\newdimen\wwo\wwo=#1%
\newdimen\wwl\wwl=\wwo\divide \wwl by #3%
\makebox[\wwo][#2]{\rule{\wwl}{1pt}}}

\begin{tabular}{ @{}>{\centering}p{6cm} @{}>{\centering}p{6cm} @{}>{\centering}p{6cm} @{}p{0.01cm} @{}>{\centering}p{6cm}X}
aaa & & bbb & & ccc \\
ddd & & eee & & fff \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Error message is :

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 

l.16 ddd &
           & eee & & fff \\
?
```

I am using :

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
```

on a Mac

Can someone help??

Thanks

Comment: unrelated to your question but don't do `\newdimen\wwo\wwo=#1%` (or the other newdimen. this will allocate 2 dimensions wach time you use it (and there are only a finite number of those, 256 in classic tex) move the \newdimen statements to the preamble so you only allocate them once

Answer (score 5):

`\\` is ambiguous: end of line inside cell or end of table row?

`\tabularnewline` explicitly ends a table row:

```
\begin{tabular}{ @{}>{\centering}p{6cm} @{}>{\centering}p{6cm}
@{}>{\centering}p{6cm} @{}p{0.01cm} @{}>{\centering}p{6cm}X}
aaa & & bbb & & ccc \tabularnewline
ddd & & eee & & fff \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The following new lines are available:

- `\tabularnewline`: ends a table row to start a new one
- `\newline` ends a line inside a cell (column type `p`)
- `\\`: Usually it ends a table row unless

  - `\centering`, `\raggedright`, `\raggedleft` are used inside the column specification. These commands redefines `\\` as `\newline`.
  - The latter can be reversed, if `\arraybackslash` is invoked after `\centering` or friends. The macro is provided by package `array` and redefines `\\` to be `\tabularnewline. Then`\` ends a table row.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{3cm} p{3cm}}
row 1, col 1, line 1\newline
row 1, col 1, line 2
&
row 1, col2, line 1\newline
row 1, col2, line 2
\\
\hline
row 2, col 1
&
row 2, col2
\tabularnewline
row 3, col 1
&
row 3, col2
\end{tabular}

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{>{\centering}p{3cm} >{\centering}p{3cm}}
row 1, col 1, line 1\\
row 1, col 1, line 2
&
row 1, col2, line 1\\
row 1, col2, line 2
\tabularnewline
\hline
row 2, col 1, line 1\newline
row 2, col 1, line 2
&
row 2, col2, line 1\newline
row 2, col2, line 2
\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}}
row 1, col 1, line 1\newline
row 1, col 1, line 2
&
row 1, col2, line 1\newline
row 1, col2, line 2
\\
\hline
row 2, col 1, line 1\newline
row 2, col 1, line 2
&
row 2, col2, line 1\newline
row 2, col2, line 2
\tabularnewline
\hline
row 3, col 1
&
row 3, col2
\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result example]

Comment: Or use `\centering\arraybackslash` in the table preamble.